# How to convert JS multi-line string to single-line with tabs

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, converters

I want to take a string, such as

```
const code = `
<code>
    This is some code
</code>
`
```

and convert it **automatically** to a one line string, using \n for breaks and \t for tabs.

After conversion it should look like:

const code = "`\n\tThis is some code\n`"

How can this be done in JavaScript? I saw posts solving how to add line breaks, but found nothing for tab support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one solution could be to find 4 spaces  and replace it by `\t` like this:

```js
const code = `
<code>
    This is some code
</code>
`;
const result = code.replace(/ {4}/g, '\\t').replace(/<\/*code>\n?/g, '').replace(/\n/g, '\\n');
console.log(result);
```

since OP has said result should be `\n\tThis is some code\n`, I've also replaced `<code></code>` with empty string.